# error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token after changing a macro

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

In a C program (u-boot), to check if the program runs that macro, I changed a define state
from

```
#define debug_cond(cond, fmt, args...)                  \
({                                  \
    if (cond)                           \
        log(LOG_CATEGORY,                   \
            (enum log_level_t)(LOGL_FORCE_DEBUG | _LOG_DEBUG),  \
            fmt, ##args);                   \
})
```

to

```
#define debug_cond(cond, fmt, args...)                  \
({                                  \
extern uint64_t myptr;              \
    if (cond) {                         \
        *((uint64_t *)myptr) = 0x801; myptr+=8; \ 
        log(LOG_CATEGORY,                   \
            (enum log_level_t)(LOGL_FORCE_DEBUG | _LOG_DEBUG),  \
            fmt, ##args);                   \
    }
})                 <==== line 267
```

and the compiles gives me this error message.

```
In file included from include/linux/printk.h:4,
                 from include/common.h:20,
                 from lib/asm-offsets.c:14:
include/log.h:267:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '}' token
  267 | })
      | ^
include/log.h:267:2: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
  267 | })
```

I can't figure out what is wrong here. Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that you have the *line-continuation* escape on all lines in the macro?

Comment: ah yes, line 266 had no `line continuation` at then end. Write a simple answer so that I can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space after the ending `\` in the 5-th macro line. Delete the trailing space:

```c
#define debug_cond(cond, fmt, args...)                  \
({                                  \
extern uint64_t myptr;              \
    if (cond) {                         \
        *((uint64_t *)myptr) = 0x801; myptr+=8; \
        log(LOG_CATEGORY,                   \
            (enum log_level_t)(LOGL_FORCE_DEBUG | _LOG_DEBUG),  \
            fmt, ##args);                   \
    }
})
```

The space breaks the macro definition in half and the second half is being interpreted by the compiler leading to a syntax error.

Turning on the "Show whitespace characters" option of your editor might be quite helpful in the long run.